# How do I get everyone working on the project to read from the same file path c#

Tags: c#, file, path, readfile

I want to read cassandra scripts in a file. I give the file path but it points to another file. I want everyone working on the project to read from the file path.

I got this error:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\yedek\14.8.20 updaterdan önce\New folder\cross\Updater\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\ABC\CassandraScripts\LiveScripts'.'
```

but the path I want to access is:

```
C:\yedek\14.8.20 updaterdan önce\New folder\cross\ABC\CassandraScripts\LiveScripts\

  string[] fileList = File_Control("./ABC/CassandraScripts/LiveScripts/");
        
            for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Length; i++)
            {
                char[] file_split = { '.', '/', '\\' };
                //dosya yolunu parse eder.
                string[] versionNameList = fileList[i].Split(file_split);
                //script dosya ismini alır.
                string versionName = versionNameList[versionNameList.Length - 1];
                //script dosya ismini parse eder.
                char[] char_split = { 'v', '.', '_'};
                string[] version = versionName.Split(char_split);
                string[] v = new string[3];

                   for (int j = 1; j < version.Length-2; j++)
                      {
                          v[j - 1] = version[j];

                      }
                string vers = string.Concat(v);

    public static string[] File_Control(string fileName)
        {
            string[] fileTest = Directory.GetFiles(@fileName);
        
            return fileTest;
        }
```

Comment: is the file path in the same file directory for everyone?

Comment: in different file directory

Comment: The only solution you can do is for everyone to read the file from the project file extension, because everyone's computer file extensions or drive names can be different.
Okay,if you make everyone the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my problem:

string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles("../../../../XYZ/CassandraScripts/LiveScripts/");

```
        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Length; i++)
        {
            char[] file_split = { '/', '\\' };
            //dosya yolunu parse eder.
            string[] versionNameList = fileList[i].Split(file_split);
            //script dosya ismini alır.
            string versionName = versionNameList[versionNameList.Length - 1];
            //script dosya ismini parse eder.
            char[] char_split = { 'v', '.', '_'};
            string[] version = versionName.Split(char_split);
            string[] v = new string[3];

               for (int j = 1; j < version.Length-2; j++)
                  {
                      v[j - 1] = version[j];

                  }
            string vers = string.Concat(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution you can do is for everyone to read the file from the project file extension, because everyone's computer file extensions or drive names can be different.

```
    string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

    string pathAlternative = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

Comment: It takes from bin file. It did not solve my problem. Thank you for your help.